# What is experimental::private_use?

Tags: perl, warnings

Inside of `perldoc perlwarn` there is a special category for `experimental::private_use`. What does `private_use` this warn on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was added by [this commit](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/commit/21c34e9717de1e37a5e25d2e7d748da66c781488), which explains the following:

> I am starting to write a Unicode::Private_Use module which will allow
> one to specify the Unicode properties of private use code points, thus
> making them actually useful.  This commit adds a hook to regcomp.c to
> accommodate this module.  The changes are pretty minimal.  This way we
> don't have to wait another release cycle to get it out there.
>
> I don't want to document this interface, until it's proven.

Currently, the feature is used in the function that parses the interior of `\p{}` and `\P{}`.

Comment: (The function that was modified is 1,406 lines long!)

Answer (score 1):

For right now, this is only documented in [perldiag](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/blead/pod/perldiag.pod),

```
The `private_use` feature is `experimental`
(S `experimental::private_use`) This feature is actually a hook for future use.
```

I think it's [likely something to do with unicode](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/b6dbf1d39057ebab301f6e56d7c7ebcd44cefe8b/lib/unicore/extracted/DGeneralCategory.txt#L3337), which seems to have [Private Use Areas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas).